# how to create custom field to custom page type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop one page portfolio wordpress theme .I have a custom post type, called "portfolio". Every posts from portfolio will be displayed in a custom template name portfolio-tempalte. Its my psd of the template.

http://s29.postimg.org/g4g7pr307/ask.png

1st post from custom post type will be displayed at the top, then 2nd post will be displayed at the bottom of 1st post. And it will be going on like this way. But the problem is, if you see my psd template there are completely different background color in different posts . I want to be able to define background color based on users hex color code input.

To do this I have decided to use custom field. Although I dont have enough knowledge about custom field.

So I need help , how to add custom field to custom post type in wordpress. If it is not possible with custom field then please suggest me how to do that.

Comment: I think you need to refer here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/adding-custom-fields-to-a-custom-post-type-the-right-way

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Advanced custom fields. Hope this helps you